# Why does modelling t-SNE 2D coordinates with a neural network fail to produce a perfect fit?

Tags: neural-networks, tsne

In short, I want to train a neural network to project my high dimensional objects to a 2D plane coordinates which was created using t-SNE (`Rtsne` package for R).

I processed 0.5 million of 128-dimensional points to this picture:

[image]

It is just OK to me. I see the clusters. Now I train the NN with the same inputs and two outputs in an attempt to get a machine capable of mapping future samples to this plane. However, I could not get a close approximation with even very complex NN (3 layers, 1014, 512, 2 neurons), as well as with a weaker model.

[image]

**So, I wonder if this is technically not possible to get exact approximation due to some randomness in the process of the t-SNE convergence, in other words, if there are contradictory examples?**

**Update 1 - Experiments with NN architecture:**

I Z-normalized inputs to unit standard deviation and zero mean.

I normalized outputs to the range [0;1].

I use Keras for R:

Per amoeba's idea I decided to kick off with the following architecture:

```
# set NN

input <- layer_input(
     shape = list(as.integer(embedding_dim))
     , name = 'input'
)

common_dense1 <- layer_dense(units = 2048, activation = "elu")

x_dense2 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "elu")

x_dense3 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "elu")

x_dense4 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "elu")

x_dense5 <- layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "elu")

x_dense6 <- layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "linear")

y_dense2 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "elu")

y_dense3 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "elu")

y_dense4 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "elu")

y_dense5 <- layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "elu")

y_dense6 <- layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "linear")

tsne_model_output_x <- 
  input %>%
  #common_dense1 %>%
  x_dense2 %>%
  x_dense3 %>%
  x_dense4 %>%
  x_dense5 %>%
  x_dense6

tsne_model_output_y <- 
  input %>%
  #common_dense1 %>%
  y_dense2 %>%
  y_dense3 %>%
  y_dense4 %>%
  y_dense5 %>%
  y_dense6

tsne_output <- layer_concatenate(inputs = c(tsne_model_output_x, tsne_model_output_y))

tsne_model <- keras_model(
  inputs = input
  , outputs = tsne_output
)

keras::compile(
     tsne_model
     , optimizer = 'adam'
     , loss = 'mse'
)


## check correctness

xtrain <- array_reshape(rnorm(100 * embedding_dim), dim = c(100, embedding_dim), order = 'C')

ytrain <- array_reshape(rnorm(100 * 2), dim = c(100, 2), order = 'C')

model_train <- fit(
     tsne_model
     , xtrain
     , ytrain
     , epochs = 1
     , batch_size = 100
     , verbose = 1
)

predict(
     tsne_model
     , xtrain
)
```

Please note it is a parallel architecture, where each coordinate is modeled using its own layers.

I roughly estimated this model comtains 2.2 Billion of parameters.

Learning rate is 1e-3.

[image]

Final MSE: 0.013. Which means average absolute error is 0.114 (or 11% given the scale of the outputs). This is worse than I've seen before.

Next I will decrease the leraning rate to 5e-4 for another 500 epochs.

**Stage 2 - smaller learning rate, larger batch size:**

[image]

**It seems we are stuck.**

Comment: This is not about tSNE. A complex enough network trained long enough should be able to fit *anything*. So presumably your network is not complex enough or is not trained efficiently enough.

Comment: @amoeba. That is good to hear, thank you. I think I understand: a NN can perfectly fit any noise even if it is present in my training samples. So, can I reformulate my question, for 0.5 million vectors of length 128, how complex the net should be? I tried so loarge architecture it did not fit in 32Gb RAM, or if not I ran it for 200,000+ episodes and still fif not get the 100% fit.

Comment: I am not a neural network expert but I would try deeper/broader architecture (something like 128->1024->1024->1024->512->256->2), exponential linear units, Adam optimizer and train for longer. If you want to get advice from experts, post your *exact* architecture and optimisation procedure and a plot of your loss during training. Note that trying to achieve zero training set loss is a recipe for overfitting (which is relevant if you have any validation or test set in mind).

Comment: @amoeba. Thank you. Let me try a broader architecure, and later I will post my training progress. I do want to overfit in my case just for experimentation. I want my clustering algorithm to see clusters in 2D and show them to people.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to train a neural network with desired quality (almost 100% overfitting):

```
# set NN

input <- layer_input(
     shape = list(as.integer(embedding_dim))
     , name = 'input'
)

dense1 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "tanh")

dense2 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "tanh")

dense3 <- layer_dense(units = 1024, activation = "tanh")

dense4 <- layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "sigmoid")

tsne_output <- 
  input %>%
  dense1 %>%
  dense2 %>%
  dense3 %>%
  dense4

tsne_model <- keras_model(
  inputs = input
  , outputs = tsne_output
)


keras::compile(
     tsne_model
     , optimizer = 'adam'
     , loss = 'mse'
)
```

Inputs were Z-normalized, and outputs were scaled to [0;1].

Training took about 10,000 epochs with batch size (500,000 / 64), but I varied this number during training, and learning rate that worked well was 1e-4 to 5e-5.

Generated image:
[image]

Correlation test:
[image]

Final epochs:

[image]

I could go on, but this quality is just enough.

**Some thoughts about what was important:**

I failed using `elu` activations in surpsiging way: produced image contained intersecting lines representing densed points at different angles, which made me think it was local minima and it looked weired and more like modern art.

When I used parallel layers for x and y coordinates the image contained two orthogonal lines with dense points (like a sniper crosshair), which was also a kinf of local minima.

I also experimented with input and output preprocessing, and output layer activation. Surprisingly, when an output layer was linearly activated, the image became quadratic.

Besides, a batch size was **really important**. Again, surprisingly, the larger batch size I set (let's say 500,000 / 8) the worst the converge I got. What worked well is smaller batch size, and this is really solid as I observed this numerous times.

After 3 weeks of on-and-off experiments I found that classic `tanh` and `sigmoid` and with classic preprocessing works well.

I cannot say analytically why this configuration behaves well, it is very black box, but somehow I found it intuitively.

**But the funniest thing is:**

Since I overfitted heavily, and I had found that overfitting starts pretty early, meaning that `tSNE` produces stochastic and noisy patterns to learn, the neural network prediction that I got on the **new data** (which are actually news texts) looks like a muddy spot as if there are no clusters. It is laughing at my efforts. Don't overfit. ) But if I did not overfit, I would get a blurry picture as well, hmm.

[image]

Comment: +1 but what was the crucial change that allowed this to happen? It's not very clear from your answer right now.

Comment: @amoeba, I added my thoughts to the answer, not very clear, but a little guidance.